# How to receive the protected object from the client, in an .phtml file 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to get a value from the database and insert into an input, so I need to get that customer object in front-end phtml file.
EXAMPLE:
**What I need to do is**: Here I get the value of the object I need,
I put in a variable, and then I put in the input

teste.phtml
getCustomer() <---  I do not know how to call the object, it only returns me protected

```
<input type="text" value="<here object value from client object>"/>
```

Comment: You want to pass whole `customer` object in your input type?

Comment: not just a value, for example, the first name, in my case the value is the CPF (a numeric attribute value in Brazil)

Comment: Can you please add some more info and code?

Comment: Being in the checkout, in the form of payment, I need to get an attribute that is in the customer database and put an entry from the bank slip, but I do not know to bring this information to put in this entry, The code is just that, a entry in which I need to pass on the value of it, an attribute that is in the client database, this PHTML file is part of an extension that I installed, in form of payment, mundipagg

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I am using cookies in javascript, I search where the object is being generated in the backend and I create a cookie to be seen in my custom phtml page.